# Parallel brute-force solution for Project Euler 4 (Largest palindrome product)

Tags: beginner, programming-challenge, concurrency, go, palindrome

The **pe4Concurrent.go** file given below is my first attempt at writing a concurrent programme, **pe4.go** is a non-concurrent implementation of the same algorithm for comparison purposes.

The algorithm itself is a simple, brute force solution to one of the Project Euler problems.

Basically, I'm very new to both Go and concurrency and would appreciated any suggestions as to how the efficiency or elegance of my use of channels and goroutines in **pe4Concurrent.go** might be improved.

Non-concurrent brute force solution (included for comparison purposes):

**pe4.go**

```
//Project Euler: Problem 4

//Largest palindrome product

//A palindromic number reads the same both ways. The largest
//palindrome made from the product of two 2-digit numbers is
//9009 = 91 × 99.

//Find the largest palindrome made from the product of two
//3-digit numbers.

package main

import "fmt"
import "time"

func isPalindrome(s string) bool {
    if len(s) <= 1 {
        return true
    }
    if s[0] != s[len(s)-1] {
        return false
    }
    s = s[:len(s)-1]
    s = s[1:]
    return isPalindrome(s)
}

func main() {

    start := time.Now()

    highestPal := 0

    lowerLimit := 100

    upperLimit := 1000

    for i := upperLimit - 1; i >= lowerLimit; i-- {

        for j := i - 1; j > 0; j-- {

            candidate := i * j

            s := fmt.Sprintf("%d", candidate)

            if isPalindrome(s) {

                if candidate > highestPal {

                    highestPal = candidate
                }
            }
        }
    }

    elapsed := time.Since(start)

    //num := 1000 * 999
    //s := fmt.Sprintf("%d", num)
    //output := isPalindrome(s)
    //fmt.Println(output)
    //output = isPalindrome("101")
    //fmt.Println(output)
    //output = isPalindrome("9")
    fmt.Println(highestPal)
    fmt.Println("Programme execution time %s", elapsed)
}
```

Concurrent brute force solution:

**pe4Concurrent.go**

```
//Project Euler: Problem 4

//Largest palindrome product

//A palindromic number reads the same both ways. The largest
//palindrome made from the product of two 2-digit numbers is
//9009 = 91 × 99.

//Find the largest palindrome made from the product of two
//3-digit numbers.

// Note:
// Brute force solution launching 900 goroutines outperforms
// the same algorithms without goroutines by a factor of
// five: 14 ms vs. 72 ms.

package main

import "fmt"
import "time"

func isPalindrome(s string) bool {
    if len(s) <= 1 {
        return true
    }
    if s[0] != s[len(s)-1] {
        return false
    }
    s = s[:len(s)-1]
    s = s[1:]
    return isPalindrome(s)
}

func getHighestPal(i int, c chan int) {

    for j := i - 1; j > 0; j-- {

        candidate := i * j

        s := fmt.Sprintf("%d", candidate)

        if isPalindrome(s) {

            c <- candidate
        }
    }
}

func main() {

    start := time.Now()

    highestPal := 0

    lowerLimit := 100

    upperLimit := 1000

    c := make(chan int)

    for i := upperLimit - 1; i >= lowerLimit; i-- {

        go getHighestPal(i, c)
    }

    for i := 0; i < upperLimit-lowerLimit; i++ {

        candidate := <-c

        if candidate > highestPal {

            highestPal = candidate
        }
    }

    elapsed := time.Since(start)
    fmt.Println(highestPal)
    fmt.Println("Programme execution time %s", elapsed)
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### Brute Force.

Your use of go-routines is pretty simple, but effective. The part I don't think is best, is the use of the channel. The channel itself is good, but the control structures you have to read content from the channel, could be better. In fact, you have a bug in them (although you are lucky that the data means you don't encounter the bug).

Let me describe the bug, first. You assume that every go-routine is going to add a value to the channel (there will be at least one palindrome). You also assume there is at most one palindrome. If there end up being fewer palindromes than routines, you may end up "hanging" on the channel when all routines are done, but no values are coming. If there are more palindromes than routines, you may have the "max" palindrome happen later in the channel than you read.

I would recommend using a wait-group for the go-routine, and then closing the channel in the completion. In essence, I would restructure the code:

> ```
> lowerLimit := 100
>
> upperLimit := 1000
>
> c := make(chan int)
>
> for i := upperLimit - 1; i >= lowerLimit; i-- {
>
>     go getHighestPal(i, c)
> }
>
> for i := 0; i < upperLimit-lowerLimit; i++ {
>
>     candidate := <-c
>
>     if candidate > highestPal {
>
>         highestPal = candidate
>     }
> }
> ```

to be:

```
lowerLimit := 100
upperLimit := 1000

count := upperLimit - 1 - lowerLimit

palindromes := make(chan int, 1024)

var wg sync.WaitGroup
wg.Add(count)
for i := 0; i < count; i++ {
    go func(val int) {
        getHighestPal(val, palindromes)
        wg.Done()
    }(i + lowerLimit)
}

go func() {
    // wait for all routines to complete
    wg.Wait()
    // close the channel to allow the terminal range
    close(palindromes)
}()

highestPal := 0
for candidate := range palindromes {
    if candidate > highestPal {
        highestPal = candidate
    }
}
```

Note how the internals of the `getHighestPal` no longer affect the reading of the channel? Also note how Ihave to create the closure parameter `i + lowerLimit` inside the go-routine call in order to have the right context for each routine.

A second bug you have is the elimination of square numbers. Again, it does not affect the results in this instance, but the code in `getHighestPal` should be `for j := i` and not `j := i - 1`. All squares of values containing only `1` digits are famously palindromes: `1111 * 1111` is `1234321` for example.

Finally, your method `getHighestPal` implies it gets the highest palindrome, but it gets all palindromes..... not just the highest.

#### Non-Brute-Force

So, a couple of other things to consider.

The `fmt.Sprintf` is slower than `strconv.Itoa`. Consider that change (it's 2 to 3 times slower in my tests).

Also, you can be creative about what you do in your algorithm to improve performance. I took your code and ran it my way.....

```
func isPalindrome(v int) bool {
    str := strconv.Itoa(v)
    right := len(str) - 1
    left := 0
    for left < right {
        if str[left] != str[right] {
            return false
        }
        left++
        right--
    }
    return true
}

func maxPalindrome(maxfact int) int {

    max := -1
    minlow := 0

    // establish a low and high value pair as the values that create the product.     
    for low := maxfact; low >= minlow; low-- {
        for high := maxfact; high >= low; high-- {
            prod := low * high
            if prod <= max {
                // no need to keep looking for things that can't possibly be larger than previous max.
                break
            }
            if isPalindrome(prod) {
                max = prod
                // limit how far we search back to things that would exceed the smallest factor
                minlow = max / maxfact
            }
        }
    }

    return max
}
```

When run in the same way as your code:

```
func main() {
    start := time.Now()

    maxp := maxPalindrome(999)

    elapsed := time.Since(start)
    fmt.Println(maxp)
    fmt.Println("Programme execution time %s", elapsed)

}
```

I was substantially faster.

On my machine, your sequential code returned:

> ```
> 906609
> Programme execution time %s 99.33103ms
> ```

your concurrent code returned:

> ```
> 906609
> Programme execution time %s 26.010698ms
> ```

And the above code returned:

> ```
> 906609
> Programme execution time %s 206.964µs
> ```

- about 100 times faster than your concurrent code.

Comment: Thanks very much for the criticism, advice and suggestions. I've had some problems getting your brute force improvement to run, though. If I run it as is I get a `type sync.WaitGroup is not an expression` error. And if I change `wg := sync.WaitGroup` to `var wg sync.WaitGroupt` I get a `fatal error: all goroutines are asleep - deadlock! goroutine 1 [semacquire]:` error. Any chance you could set me straight on what I'm missing here?

Comment: sure... let me actually run the code too.

Comment: Hmmm... I have to head out for a few hours.... proimise I will look back in to the sync. It should be `var sync.WaitGroup` at least. I know the problem at least, though, which is that the channel yu have is unbuffered (no int argument in the `make`) and the "collection" should porobably be in a different go-routine so you cans tart collecting before the wg.Wait.

Comment: Thanks. I'll see if I can work out a solution myself in the meantime.

Comment: @R.Duke - I have edited the example. Have a look at the revision history to see the changes too: http://codereview.stackexchange.com/posts/153798/revisions

Comment: That's awesome. Thanks so much. Just three questions so that I can understand your solution. 1. Where does the `1024` figure come from? It seems both very precise and rather arbitrary. Could you change it? 2. Why does `wg.Wait()` need to be in a goroutine? I would have thought that the waiting for threads to finish had to happen in the main programme thread. 3. Could you recommend any good resources for learning about concurrency in go (so I can stop bothering you about it)?

Comment: The 1024 is "arbitrary", it's just a buffer, and if background go-routines find palindromes faster than they are "maxed", then they will "pause" when the channel has 1024 items.... allowing the "max" routine to catch up. I figured "about a thousand" is enough... and I tend to round things to powers of 2 - a habit. You can change it to anything, but changing it to 0 means only one go-routine at a time can use the channel.... making it "sequential" at that point.

Comment: Either the `wg.wait`, or the `max` loop has to be in a separate go-routine. I chose the `wg.wait` because it has no output data to "get". It's complicated, but if the parallel goroutines fill the buffer/channel, they will block, and the `wg.wait` won't exit, and since the code to empty the channel is after the wg.wait (because the wait has to close the channel), one of them has to be in a separate routine.

Comment: I recommend the "concurrency" effective go: https://golang.org/doc/effective_go.html?h=concurrency#concurrency